# askopenfilename() disables editing tkinter Entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using the following code to open a file, read its lines into a list and filter them using a substring from an Entry:

```
def get_entries(self):
    """
    Open a file and load entries into a list.
    """

    try:
        # self.file_name = "p1.py"
        self.file_name = askopenfilename(title="Open file")
        self.file_handle = open(self.file_name, "r")
    except IOError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "No file has been openned.")
        self.destroy()
    else:
        self.entry_list = self.file_handle.readlines()
        self.update_list()

def update_list(self, *args):
    """
    Update the list after each editing of the search filter
    """

    search_term = self.search_var.get()

    self.lbox.delete(*self.lbox.get_children())

    for index, item in enumerate(self.entry_list):
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            self.lbox.insert('', END, values=(index, item))
```

Why does it work fine using `self.file_name = "p1.py"` but using `askopenfilename()` disables editing the Entry? 
Minimizing and restoring the window with the Entry fixes the problem.

I'm using PyCharm on Windows 10

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.file_name = ""
        self.file_handle = ""
        self.entry_list = None

        self.search_label = Label(self, text="Filter: ")
        self.search_var = StringVar()
        self.search_var.trace("w", self.update_list)
        self.search_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.search_var)

        self.lbox = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('indices', 'entries'), displaycolumns='entries', show='headings')
        self.lbox.heading('entries', text="Entries", anchor="w")

        self.confirm = Button(self, text="Confirm", width=10, command=self.confirm_action)
        self.cancel = Button(self, text="Cancel", width=10, command=quit)

        self.search_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, padx=12, pady=5)
        self.search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=4, pady=5)
        self.lbox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=(N, W, S, E), padx=12, pady=5)

        self.cancel.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
        self.confirm.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=12, pady=5)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="u")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="u")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=4, uniform="u")

        self.get_entries()

    def get_entries(self): ...

    def update_list(self, *args): ...

    def confirm_action(self): ...


root = Tk()
root.title('Filter Listbox Test')
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I can confirm it happens in Windows 7 but not in Debian Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem due to calling the askfilename before the root window is drawn. As a workaround you can add `self.update()` before you call `askopenfilename`.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # ... stuff ...

        self.update()
        self.get_entries()
```

I'll file a bug report about this right now.

Comment: I think a bug was filed on this several  years ago. It may have been filed on the tcl/tk bug database rather than the tkinter one. I think the bug only appears on windows, but I could be wrong about that.